# Excess elements in array initializer initializing 2D array using variable

Tags: c

I'm trying to initialize all the values of array N[][] to 0 but I get excess elements in array initializer

```
int M = 5;
int N[5][M] = {0}
```

Comment: You can't initialize VLAs. Post a [mre] that shows the error you note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually initialize VLA array.

if you want to zero it use memset as in my example. If you want something more complex you need to write your own code to do so.

```
int init(void *array, size_t size, int *initializer, size_t isize)
{
    unsigned char *wrk = array;
    if(initializer)
    {
        memcpy(wrk, initializer, isize);
    }
    else
    {
        isize = 0;
    }
    memset(wrk + isize, 0, size - isize);
    return array;
}

int main() 
    {
    int M = 5;
    int Z = 5;
    int N[Z][M];

    memset((void *)N, 0, sizeof(N));

    for (int i = 0; i < Z; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%d ", N[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    init(N, sizeof(N), (int[]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(int) * 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < Z; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%d ", N[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```