# Not sure how to deal with the error "excess elements in array initializer"

Tags: c

In line 10 I cannot find out where my problem is at first.  I place `int a[100][100]={0}` but the cpu speed is stuck.
Then, I try to change it into `a[n][n]` but no output is shown.
Last, I try to change it again as if it resembles the original ones.
However, nothing works instead of a new question.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;

  while (scanf("%d", &n)) {
    n *= 2;
    int x = 0, y = 0, num = 1;
    int a[n][n] = {0};
    a[x][y] = num++;
    while (n * n >= num) //定義陣列
    {
      while (y + 1 < n && !a[x][y + 1]) //向右
        a[x][++y] = num++;

      while (x + 1 < n && !a[x + 1][y]) //向下
        a[++x][y] = num++;

      while (y - 1 >= 0 && !a[x][y - 1]) //向左
        a[x][--y] = num++;

      while (x - 1 >= 0 && !a[x - 1][y]) //向上
        a[--x][y] = num++;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++) //print 陣列
        {
      for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        if (y != n - 1) {
          printf("%d ", a[x][y]);
        } else {
          printf("%d", a[x][y]);
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posted code does _not_ give that error. Did you post the real code? Did you post the real error? You can't initialize VLAs but that problem will yield an entirely different compiler error.

Comment: What compiler do you use and which version? How do you compile?

Comment: About `while (scanf("%d", &n))`, please remember that `scanf` may return `EOF`.

Comment: Check should always be `scanf(...) == numberOfScannedElements`, i.e. `== 1` in your case...

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem:

Variable Length Arrays ([VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99)) cannot be initialized via the C standard.

Alternate, *assign* via `memset()` after defining `a`.

```
// int a[n][n]={0};
int a[n][n];
memset(a, 0, sizeof a);
```

Comment: Yes I was about to post this answer too, but it wouldn't yield "excess elements in array initializer". But rather "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized". So something in the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lundin True.  I suspect the compiler may use an extension and dynamically whine when `n==0`.  Or perhaps something lost in translation.  Perhaps output of a static code analyzer?

Comment: @Lundin Hmm [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63544577/2410359) is likewise.  I think the compilier is saying "excess" because for a VLA, even one initializer is 1 too mnany.

Comment: Unlikely. gcc gives the exact verbatim "error: excess elements in array initializer" for code like `int a [1]={1,2};`. clang too. But a different message for attempting to initializate a VLA.

Comment: @Lundin Of course gcc is not the only C compiler. ;-)  [exact warning example](https://www.coder.work/article/1543453)

Comment: But if gcc and clang both gives the exact verbatim for a different bug... what other compiler is there which gives the same text but for VLA?

Comment: @Lundin Search for "excess elements in array initializer" provides evidence that _some_ compiler will emit that.   "what other compiler is there which gives the same text but for VLA?" --> unsure, yet there are numerous compilers and versions to check: [C compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers).  You could ask OP what compiler was used.